# Liferay service builder JNDI lookup uses the wrong naming context

Tags: spring, tomcat, jndi, liferay-6, contextclassloader

I have a servicebuilder portlet that is configured via JNDI:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" useHttpOnly="true">
  <ResourceLink name="app/url" global="my-app/app/url"
    type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

In my `ext-spring.xml`, I try to pull that value using:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/app/url" />
```

However, the `InitialContext`that is used to look this value up, seems to be the `InitialContext` of the `ROOT` webapp (liferay itself) as the only thing it contains is the `java:comp/env/jdbc/LiferayPool` database connection pool.  I know JNDI contexts are tied to the the `ClassLoader` determined by:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

And I know liferay mucks with the classloader before running the portlet initialization.  But I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get around this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution for you but it is a little bit different of what you've described in your post.

First of all, I propose you to move the declaration of JNDI to **server.xml** of Tomcat, specifically to *< GlobalNamingResources >* tag.

Here is an example:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource
   name="jdbc/CustomDBPoolShared"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@YOUR_SERVER:1521:YOUR_SERVICE"
   username="USERNAME"
   password="PASSWORD"
   maxActive="20"
   maxIdle="5"
   maxWait="10000"
/>
......
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

After that you should make a *ResourceLink* in **context.xml**:

```
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/CustomDBPool" global="jdbc/CustomDBPoolShared" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
....
</Context>
```

This will help you to deal with concurrent access if ever you'll have two portlets accessing the same database.

And, finally, ext-spring.xml:

```
   <!-- Custom Beans -->
<bean id="digitalHibernateSessionFactory" class="com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortletHibernateConfiguration" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="customDBDataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="customDBSessionFactory" class="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryImpl" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactoryImplementor">
        <ref bean="digitalHibernateSessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="customDBDataSourceTarget" class="com.liferay.portal.spring.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/customDBPool</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="customDBDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <ref bean="customDBDataSourceTarget" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Notice the    
    
        
            
        
    
    
        
            
        
    
    
        
            jdbc/customDBPool

Please note the **jdbc/customDBPool** which is described in **context.xml** and which is available not only for ROOT classloader.

In the end you should reference the proper dataSource in your service.xml of LiferayServiceBuilder like that:

```
<entity name="MyCustomEntity" table="CUSTOM_ENTITY" local-service="true" remote-service="false" data-source="customDBDataSource" session-factory="customDBSessionFactory" cache-enabled="false">
.....
</entity>
```